# Fix mixing of files inside folders while renaming folders

Tags: python, directory

```
import os 
root_path = 'C://Users//Downloads//Practice'
s=[]
for i in range(80,130):
    n='Name'
    Folder=n+str(i)
    s.append(Folder)
print(len(s))
###########################RENAMING FOLDERS
for i,j in enumerate(os.listdir(root_path)):
    src=root_path+"//"+j
    dst=root_path+"//"+s[i]
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

I have 50 folders, I am able to rename all folders at once using the above code but the images inside them are mixing up. For example: Folder 1 images saved in Folder 3.
How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: You want to rename files using numbers like ```0...1...2```?

Comment: No, I want to rename just the folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use glob.

```
import glob
dir_list = os.listdir(root_path)
# if endwith "/", may glob only folders
dir_list += glob.glob(root_path+"//*//") 
dir_list = list(set(dir_lsit))
for i,j in enumerate(dir_list):
    src=root_path+"//"+j
    dst=root_path+"//"+s[i]
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
root_path = 'C://Users//Practice'
s=[]
for i in range(80,130):
    n='Name'
    Folder=n+str(i)
    s.append(Folder)
print(len(s))
from pathlib import Path
text = sorted(Path(root_path).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)
text
##################################################RENAMING FOLDERS
for i,j in enumerate(os.listdir(root_path)):
    src=text[i]
    dst=root_path+"//"+s[i]
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation